# What is a good approach to check if an item is in a very big hashset?

Tags: hashset, bigdata

I have a hashset that cannot be entirely loaded into the memory. So let's say it has ABC part and each one could be loaded into memory but not all at one time.
I also have random entries coming in from time to time which I can barely tell which part it could potentially belong to. So one of the approaches could be that I load A first and then make a check, and then B, C. But next entry could belong to B so I have to unload C, and then load A, then B...Hopefully I make this understood.

This clearly would be very slow so I wonder is there a better way to do that? (if using db is not an alternative)

Comment: use a database with appropriate index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you don't use some criteria to put data entry either to A or to B. In other words, A,B,C - it's just result of division of whole data to 3 equal parts. Am I right? If so I recommend you add some criteria when you adding new entry to your set. For example, if your entries are numbers put those who starts from 0-3 to A, those who starts from 4-6 - to B, from 7-9 to C. When your search something, you apriori now that you have to search in A or in B, or in C. If your entries are words - the same solution, but now criteria is first letter. May be here better use not 3 sets but 26 - size of english alphabet. Please note, that you anyway have to store one of sets in memory. You see one advantage - you do maximum 1 load/unload operation, you don't need to check all sets - you now which of them can really store your value. This idea is widely using in DB - partitioning. If you store in sets nor numbers nor words but some complex objects you anyway can invent some simple criteria.